# TokenError: Code was already redeemed - Passport Google OAuth

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, passport.js

I am trying to auth my app with passportjs using email strategy.
However I always get code redeemed error. I found out that callback is being called 2 times (we see it on wireshark logs).

I opened a ticket on GitHub
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth/issues/105

Looks like it works fine for most people, but not for me.
So I'm looking for people who have experience of fixing it.

There is no need to paste source here as long as it's exactly the same code provided in examples for passportjs

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by using external ip address and specifying it for google callback url.